# Using T4MVC with .NET 4.5 in Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: t4mvc, asp.net-4.5

Does anyone know if this is possible? I can get it to work OK if I build for 4.0 compatibility but when I use 4.5 all my tests fail with the familiar;

> System.Security.VerificationException: Method
>   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression:
>   type argument 'T' violates  the constraint of type parameter
>   'TController'

Which I believe is due to a mismatched version of MVC. I've tried adding a binding redirect in the config for 4.5 but as I'd anticipate that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you get this error when the T4 template is processed (e.g. when you save it), or when you run the app? Do you have a full stack trace?

Comment: Well it was running the unit tests. I've pulled all the T4MVC in the meantime as I wanted to stick with 4.5. Are you saying you'd expect it to work?

Comment: I'm not aware of an issue. Doesn't mean there isn't one. Can you include a full stack trace?

Comment: I just did a quick test with .NET 4.5 and it seems to work fine for me. Would need a more complete repro.

Comment: Thanks David, let me get to a stable checkin and I'll try adding back to the project and see if I can repro. If so, I'll try and repro with a clean project. I did have some mixed 4.0 and 4.5 in the same solution early on but I was fairly sure it was consistent when I tested. Now azure is up to 4.5 I'm all 4.5 now, but it could be a mismatch between some other 3rd party NuGet package, although I'm not sure what would be loading MVC.

Comment: If you get a reliable repro, please e-mail me at bradwils at microsoft dot com. Thanks!

Comment: OK. I just got around to re-testing this. I just downloaded 2.9.0 with NuGet and it gave me the Serialization error at first. I ran the custom tool option over it and it seemed to build but now the generated classes are saying that my Controllers do not have a constructor that take 0 parameters (I'm using DI).